# How to get ComboBox value from DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

When I edit a cell in my datagrid a combobox is raised and I choose a value from said combobox, and when the edit ends a CellEditEnding event is triggered and I want to get the value I chose but I am not able to locate my combobox value in my event.

How can I get the value?

```
<DataGrid x:Name="ModulesTable" 
              Background="#d8deff" 
              Foreground="#383e42" 
              Grid.Row="1" 
              SelectionChanged="ModulesTable_SelectionChanged" 
              CellEditEnding="ModulesTable_CellEditEnding" 
              CanUserAddRows="False"
              CanUserDeleteRows="False"
              CanUserReorderColumns="False"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ModuleType" >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ModuleTypeName}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox Text="{Binding Path=ModuleTypeName}" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" IsEditable="True">
                            <ComboBoxItem>IZMO</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>LIMOAP</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>LIMOKO</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>VIMO</ComboBoxItem>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

This is what I have so far:

```
    private void ModulesTable_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement element1 = ModulesTable.Columns[1].GetCellContent(e.Row);
        Log.Debug("TypeOF: " + element1.GetType()); // Type is ContentPresenter
        if (element1.GetType() == typeof(ComboBox)) // This doesnt work because its not ComboBox
        {
            var value = ((ComboBox)element1).Text;
            // Get value somehow??
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you don't use a `DataGridComboBoxColumn`?

Well using MVVM i would call an `ICommand` on my ViewModel where i can simply access the bounded value of the `ComboBox`. You can bind Commands using `EventTrigger`.

First add the namespace:

```
 xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

Setting the `Interaction.Triggers`:

```
<DataGrid>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="CellEditEnding">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CellEditEndCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="RowEditEnding">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CellEditEndCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Some advice for the binding, i'm not sure if if this is needed for `ComboBox` but on `TextBox` to get the updated value you have to set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged` like this:
`Text="{Binding text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

Comment: Yeah there is a reason and that is I am very new to WPF and didn't know it existed. Thank you

Comment: no problem :) , if you new to WPF and would start with MVVM check out Prism there is a pretty good tutorial on youtube from Brian Lagunas simple search for "c# prism outlook" it will save you a lot of time!